# Conditional set_fact doesn't evaluate

Tags: ansible

I'm looking to set a variable based on the outcome of the following evaluation: `({{ found_files.files|length > 0 }})`, however, it doesn't appear to be evaluated fully. What could be the issue?

Desired outcome:`found_files2: /dev/null`

Outcome:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "found_files2": "{'files': [], 'changed': False, 'msg': '', 'matched': 0, 'examined': 0, 'failed': False} if (False) else '/dev/null'"
}
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    backup_dir: /home/user1/projects/ansible/modules/backups/router2
  tasks:

    - name: get files in backups/<router name>/
      delegate_to: localhost
      find:
        paths: "{{ backup_dir }}"
      register: found_files

    - set_fact:
        found_files2: "{{ found_files }} if ({{ found_files.files|length > 0 }}) else '/dev/null'"

    - debug: var=found_files2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is below

```
- set_fact:
    found_files2: "{{ found_files if (found_files.files|length > 0) else '/dev/null' }}"
```

The filter ternary gives the same result

```
- set_fact:                                                                                         
    found_files2: "{{ (found_files.files|length > 0)|ternary(found_files, '/dev/null') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there some manual I could refer to where it's explained why this syntax is used in this case?